# Arquivos não ignorados no gitignore VSTS

Tags: visual-studio, git

Estou fazendo um projeto compartilhado utilizando o VS Team Services, porém tem alguns arquivos que não estou conseguindo ignorar no `.gitignore.`
Como fazer para ignorar eles? arquivo (.suo), pasta(obj) e extensão(.cache)
Segue meu .gitignore abaixo

```
    # Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_
*.dll

# Files for the ART/Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/
out/

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
x64/
build/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/


# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log

# Android Studio Navigation editor temp files
.navigation/

# Android Studio captures folder
captures/

# Intellij
*.iml
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/gradle.xml
.idea/dictionaries
.idea/libraries

# Keystore files
*.jks

# External native build folder generated in Android Studio 2.2 and later
.externalNativeBuild

# Google Services (e.g. APIs or Firebase)
google-services.json

# Freeline
freeline.py
freeline/
freeline_project_description.json
/MapaMVC/.vs/AppFrete_Solution/v15/Server/sqlite3

#Compiler
*.suo
*.cache
build.force
/MapaMVC/AppFrete/AppFrete/obj/Debug/netstandard2.0
```

Comment: Como você gerouo .gitignore?

Comment: Você gerou o .gitignore depois de adicionar esses arquivos? Se sim, terás que removêlos do git para depois adicioná-los no .gitignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizei o arquivo gitignore já existente, porem já resolvi o problema utilizando o caminho absoluto para a pasta na qual desejava bloquear os arquivos de subirem.